# PIXI.js AnimatedSprite Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_uvs')

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm creating a [PIXI.js](https://pixijs.com/) animation. I'm using their `AnimatedSprite` class (documentation [here](https://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.AnimatedSprite.html)).

#### Error

I'm able to load my spritesheet and see that all the textures are defined. But **I can't use the `.play()` method on my `AnimatedSprite` instance.** This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_uvs')
    at AnimatedSprite.updateTexture (mixin-get-child-by-name.js:28)
    at AnimatedSprite.update (mixin-get-child-by-name.js:14)
    at TickerListener.emit (ticker.js:29)
    at Ticker.update (ticker.js:413)
    at Ticker._tick (ticker.js:164)

AnimatedSprite.updateTexture    @   mixin-get-child-by-name.js:28
AnimatedSprite.update   @   mixin-get-child-by-name.js:14
TickerListener.emit @   ticker.js:29
Ticker.update   @   ticker.js:413
Ticker._tick    @   ticker.js:164
requestAnimationFrame (async)       
Ticker._tick    @   ticker.js:167
requestAnimationFrame (async)       
Ticker._requestIfNeeded @   ticker.js:184
Ticker.start    @   ticker.js:329
Ticker._startIfPossible @   ticker.js:212
Ticker._addListener @   ticker.js:272
Ticker.add  @   ticker.js:226
AnimatedSprite.play @   mixin-cache-as-bitmap.js:838
loadFire    @   temp.html:42                              // THE .play() FUNCTION CAUSES THE ERROR //
Signal.dispatch @   core.js:11534
Loader._onComplete  @   loaders.js:1115
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1143
next    @   loaders.js:754
SpritesheetLoader.use   @   prepare.js:207
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
KTXLoader.use   @   compressed-textures.js:508
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
DDSLoader.use   @   compressed-textures.js:277
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
CompressedTextureLoader.use @   loaders.js:1957
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
BitmapFontLoader.use    @   text-bitmap.js:810
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1292
Promise.then (async)        
TextureLoader.use   @   loaders.js:1290
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
parsing @   loaders.js:1416
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
AsyncQueue.eachSeries   @   loaders.js:767
Loader._onLoad  @   loaders.js:1128
Signal.dispatch @   core.js:11534
exports.LoaderResource.LoaderResource._finish   @   loaders.js:60
exports.LoaderResource.LoaderResource.complete  @   extract.js:128
load (async)        
exports.LoaderResource.LoaderResource._loadElement  @   loaders.js:85
exports.LoaderResource.LoaderResource.load  @   extract.js:194
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1097
next    @   loaders.js:754
AsyncQueue.eachSeries   @   loaders.js:767
Loader._loadResource    @   loaders.js:1085
Loader._boundLoadResource   @   loaders.js:876
AsyncQueue.process  @   loaders.js:662
setTimeout (async)      
AsyncQueue._insert  @   loaders.js:650
AsyncQueue.push @   loaders.js:702
Loader._add @   loaders.js:941
add @   loaders.js:1218
SpritesheetLoader.use   @   prepare.js:247
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
KTXLoader.use   @   compressed-textures.js:508
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
DDSLoader.use   @   compressed-textures.js:277
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
CompressedTextureLoader.use @   loaders.js:1957
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
BitmapFontLoader.use    @   text-bitmap.js:810
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
TextureLoader.use   @   loaders.js:1299
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
parsing @   loaders.js:1416
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1129
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:760
setTimeout (async)      
next    @   loaders.js:759
AsyncQueue.eachSeries   @   loaders.js:767
Loader._onLoad  @   loaders.js:1128
Signal.dispatch @   core.js:11534
exports.LoaderResource.LoaderResource._finish   @   loaders.js:60
exports.LoaderResource.LoaderResource.complete  @   extract.js:128
exports.LoaderResource.LoaderResource._xhrOnLoad    @   loaders.js:316
load (async)        
exports.LoaderResource.LoaderResource._loadXhr  @   loaders.js:163
exports.LoaderResource.LoaderResource.load  @   extract.js:210
(anonymous) @   loaders.js:1097
next    @   loaders.js:754
AsyncQueue.eachSeries   @   loaders.js:767
Loader._loadResource    @   loaders.js:1085
Loader._boundLoadResource   @   loaders.js:876
AsyncQueue.process  @   loaders.js:662
AsyncQueue.resume   @   loaders.js:737
Loader.load @   loaders.js:1018
(anonymous) @   temp.html:23
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

Here's some reproducible code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Create PIXI application and add to body
    app = new PIXI.Application({
      width: 500,
      height: 500
    });
    document.body.appendChild(app.view);

    //Load spritesheet
    PIXI.Loader.shared.add("6.json").load(loadFire);

    function loadFire() {
      const s = PIXI.Loader.shared.resources["6.json"].spritesheet.textures;
      let fire = [];

      // Load frames of sprite
      for (let i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
        // Get frame number padded with 4 zeros
        j = i.toString();
        do { j = "0" + j } while (j.length < 4)

        fire.push(new PIXI.Sprite(s[`lit${j}.png`]));
      }
      fire = new PIXI.AnimatedSprite(fire);
      fire.loop = true; fire.animationSpeed = 0.5;

      // Add to stage and play
      app.stage.addChild(fire);
      fire.play();
    } 
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the [spritesheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz7VD.jpg) Save it as `6.png` in the same directory as the following JSON (`6.json`) and above html file.

```
{"frames": {

"BodyAndHead6.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":73,"y":1,"w":272,"h":521},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":121,"y":81,"w":272,"h":521},
    "sourceSize": {"w":500,"h":700}
},
"ClosedEyes6.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1608,"y":441,"w":92,"h":35},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":161,"y":205,"w":92,"h":35},
    "sourceSize": {"w":500,"h":700}
},
"Eyes6.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1,"y":465,"w":80,"h":36},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":167,"y":205,"w":80,"h":36},
    "sourceSize": {"w":500,"h":700}
},
"LeftArm6.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1402,"y":241,"w":182,"h":130},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":111,"y":415,"w":182,"h":130},
    "sourceSize": {"w":500,"h":700}
},
"lit0000.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1540,"y":1,"w":215,"h":218},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":40,"w":215,"h":218},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0001.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1540,"y":1,"w":215,"h":218},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":40,"w":215,"h":218},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0002.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1317,"y":1,"w":221,"h":238},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":47,"y":20,"w":221,"h":238},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0003.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1317,"y":1,"w":221,"h":238},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":47,"y":20,"w":221,"h":238},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0004.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":734,"y":266,"w":251,"h":243},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":17,"y":15,"w":251,"h":243},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0005.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":734,"y":266,"w":251,"h":243},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":17,"y":15,"w":251,"h":243},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0006.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":596,"y":1,"w":263,"h":253},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":5,"y":5,"w":263,"h":253},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0007.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":596,"y":1,"w":263,"h":253},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":5,"y":5,"w":263,"h":253},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0008.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1072,"y":1,"w":251,"h":243},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":17,"y":15,"w":251,"h":243},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0009.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1072,"y":1,"w":251,"h":243},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":17,"y":15,"w":251,"h":243},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0010.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1317,"y":1,"w":221,"h":238},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":47,"y":20,"w":221,"h":238},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0011.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1317,"y":1,"w":221,"h":238},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":47,"y":20,"w":221,"h":238},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0012.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1540,"y":221,"w":215,"h":218},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":40,"w":215,"h":218},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0013.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1540,"y":221,"w":215,"h":218},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":40,"w":215,"h":218},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0014.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":83,"y":275,"w":215,"h":234},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":24,"w":215,"h":234},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0015.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":83,"y":275,"w":215,"h":234},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":24,"w":215,"h":234},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0016.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":851,"y":1,"w":219,"h":253},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":5,"w":219,"h":253},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0017.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":851,"y":1,"w":219,"h":253},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":5,"w":219,"h":253},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0018.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":300,"y":275,"w":215,"h":234},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":24,"w":215,"h":234},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0019.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":300,"y":275,"w":215,"h":234},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":24,"w":215,"h":234},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0020.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1540,"y":221,"w":215,"h":218},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":40,"w":215,"h":218},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0021.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1540,"y":221,"w":215,"h":218},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":40,"w":215,"h":218},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0022.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1317,"y":1,"w":221,"h":238},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":47,"y":20,"w":221,"h":238},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0023.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1317,"y":1,"w":221,"h":238},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":47,"y":20,"w":221,"h":238},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0024.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1072,"y":1,"w":251,"h":243},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":17,"y":15,"w":251,"h":243},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0025.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1072,"y":1,"w":251,"h":243},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":17,"y":15,"w":251,"h":243},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0026.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":596,"y":1,"w":263,"h":253},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":5,"y":5,"w":263,"h":253},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0027.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":596,"y":1,"w":263,"h":253},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":5,"y":5,"w":263,"h":253},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0028.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":734,"y":266,"w":251,"h":243},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":17,"y":15,"w":251,"h":243},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0029.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":734,"y":266,"w":251,"h":243},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":17,"y":15,"w":251,"h":243},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0030.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1317,"y":1,"w":221,"h":238},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":47,"y":20,"w":221,"h":238},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0031.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1317,"y":1,"w":221,"h":238},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":47,"y":20,"w":221,"h":238},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0032.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1540,"y":1,"w":215,"h":218},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":40,"w":215,"h":218},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0033.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1540,"y":1,"w":215,"h":218},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":40,"w":215,"h":218},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0034.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":517,"y":275,"w":215,"h":234},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":24,"w":215,"h":234},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0035.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":517,"y":275,"w":215,"h":234},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":24,"w":215,"h":234},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0036.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":987,"y":256,"w":219,"h":253},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":5,"w":219,"h":253},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0037.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":987,"y":256,"w":219,"h":253},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":5,"w":219,"h":253},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0038.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":300,"y":275,"w":215,"h":234},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":24,"w":215,"h":234},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0039.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":300,"y":275,"w":215,"h":234},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":24,"w":215,"h":234},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"lit0040.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1540,"y":1,"w":215,"h":218},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":53,"y":40,"w":215,"h":218},
    "sourceSize": {"w":300,"h":300}
},
"RightArm6.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1402,"y":441,"w":204,"h":51},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":71,"y":375,"w":204,"h":51},
    "sourceSize": {"w":500,"h":700}
},
"Stick6.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1,"y":1,"w":70,"h":462},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":58,"y":90,"w":70,"h":462},
    "sourceSize": {"w":250,"h":600}
},
"Stone6.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1208,"y":254,"w":242,"h":192},
    "rotated": true,
    "trimmed": true,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":58,"y":123,"w":242,"h":192},
    "sourceSize": {"w":400,"h":400}
}},
"animations": {
    "lit": ["lit0000.png","lit0001.png","lit0002.png","lit0003.png","lit0004.png","lit0005.png","lit0006.png","lit0007.png","lit0008.png","lit0009.png","lit0010.png","lit0011.png","lit0012.png","lit0013.png","lit0014.png","lit0015.png","lit0016.png","lit0017.png","lit0018.png","lit0019.png","lit0020.png","lit0021.png","lit0022.png","lit0023.png","lit0024.png","lit0025.png","lit0026.png","lit0027.png","lit0028.png","lit0029.png","lit0030.png","lit0031.png","lit0032.png","lit0033.png","lit0034.png","lit0035.png","lit0036.png","lit0037.png","lit0038.png","lit0039.png","lit0040.png"]
},
"meta": {
    "app": "https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker",
    "version": "1.0",
    "image": "6.png",
    "format": "RGBA8888",
    "size": {"w":1756,"h":510},
    "scale": "1",
    "smartupdate": "$TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:ecfb2de4a0de7a17eb69118c3e07555b:2a2f78f5c14a53c820593548f5f3ca2f:dbe324ba66a3905eeac58a8d5e17d3a8$"
}
}
```

Also some system info:

- I'm using **PIXI.js v6.2.0**
- I'm using **Microsoft Edge Version 96.0.1054.62 (Official build) (64-bit)**
- I'm using Windows 10 10.0.19042

#### Debugging Attempts

I checked this [issue](https://github.com/pixijs/particle-emitter/issues/26) on the PIXI.js Github, but it had to do with textures that had been destroyed. My textures are loaded fine. **If I remove the `fire.play()` line, the first frame of the `AnimatedSprite` displays.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PIXI.js developer gave this answer [here](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/8074#issuecomment-1002148632):

> It is due to this part....
>
> `` fire.push(new PIXI.Sprite(s[`lit${j}.png`])); ``
>
> You are trying to create with an array of type `Sprite`, whereas as per docs it requires an array of type `Texture`.
> https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Spritesheet.html#animations
>
> So you can change your example to:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
>
> <head>
>   <meta charset="UTF-8">
>   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
>   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
>   <title>Document</title>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>
>   <script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script>
>   <script>
>     // Create PIXI application and add to body
>     app = new PIXI.Application({
>       width: 500,
>       height: 500
>     });
>     document.body.appendChild(app.view);
>
>     //Load spritesheet
>     PIXI.Loader.shared.add("6.json").load(loadFire);
>
>     function loadFire() {
>       const s = PIXI.Loader.shared.resources["6.json"].spritesheet;
>   
>       fire = new PIXI.AnimatedSprite(s.animations.lit);
>       fire.loop = true;
>       fire.animationSpeed = 0.5;
>
>       // Add to stage and play
>       app.stage.addChild(fire);
>       fire.play();
>     } 
>   </script>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

- [Dave Moore (@themoonrat)](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/8074#issuecomment-1002148632)

Answer (score 0):

**I don't have a full answer to what's going, wrong, but I found a workaround to play the animation.**

I thought that **if the first frame was displaying correctly (when I removed the `fire.play()` line), then the other ones might be too.**

I checked this by replacing the `fire.play()` line with `fire.gotoAndStop(30)`. I saw a new frame being displayed. (Sidenote: the spritesheet has 41 frames, so I could pass any number under 41 as a frame index to the `.gotoAndStop()` method.)

Since I could play all these different frames, I tried to **loop through the frames myself using `.gotoAndStop()` and `setInterval()` to play the animation**. Here's the relevant code:

```
  let i = 0;
  const firePlay = () => {
    fire.gotoAndStop(i);
    i++;
    if (i == 40) i = 0; // At the last frame, go back to the first frame
  }
  const fireInterval = setInterval(firePlay, 42); // 42 ms is about 24 frames per second
```

And here's the full HTML snippet (same JSON and spritesheet image as in the question above).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Create PIXI application and add to body
    app = new PIXI.Application({
      width: 500,
      height: 500
    });
    document.body.appendChild(app.view);

    //Load spritesheet
    PIXI.Loader.shared.add("6.json").load(loadFire);

    function loadFire() {
      const s = PIXI.Loader.shared.resources["6.json"].spritesheet.textures;
      let fire = [];

      // Load frames of sprite
      for (let i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
        // Get frame number padded with 4 zeros
        j = i.toString();
        do { j = "0" + j } while (j.length < 4)

        fire.push(new PIXI.Sprite(s[`lit${j}.png`]));
      }
      fire = new PIXI.AnimatedSprite(fire);
      fire.loop = true; fire.animationSpeed = 0.5;

      // Add to stage and play
      app.stage.addChild(fire);
      let i = 0;
      const firePlay = () => {
        fire.gotoAndStop(i);
        i++;
        if (i == 40) i = 0; // At the last frame, go back to the first frame
      };
      const fireInterval = setInterval(firePlay, 42); // 42 ms is about 24 frames per second 
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```